# query value contain `{aa%` cause feign returned http status code 400

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, netflix-feign, feign

I'm using feign in spring-cloud, I have got a problem.

This is my feign client def.

```
@FeignClient("food-service")
public interface FoodService {
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/food"},method = {RequestMethod.GET})
    List<Food> find(@RequestParam("name") String name);
}
foodService.find("{co%%");
```

this call will be returned status code 400 .

Then I review the code, and I found this code in RequestTemplate class :

```
private String encodeIfNotVariable(String in) {
    if (in == null || in.indexOf('{') == 0) {
        return in;
    }
    return urlEncode(in);
}
```

The method `encodeIfNotVariable` called in query(String name, String... values) .

This means if the value containing `{` and in the first , the value cannot to be encode.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The character { is an [unsafe character](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) so you must encode it:

> Characters can be unsafe for a number of reasons.  ....
>
> .... [missing part]....
>
> Other characters are unsafe because  gateways and other transport agents are known to sometimes modify  such characters. These characters are "{", "}", "|", "\", "^", "~",
>   "[", "]", and "`".
>
> All unsafe characters must always be encoded within a URL. For  example, the character "#" must be encoded within URLs even in  systems that do not normally deal with fragment or anchor identifiers, so that if the URL is copied into another system that  does use them, it will not be necessary to change the URL encoding.

In summary, character `{` must be encoded as `%7B`:

```
foodService.find("%7Bco%%");
```

More info:

- [unsafe character encoding](https://perishablepress.com/stop-using-unsafe-characters-in-urls/)
- [ASCII Encoding Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

Otherwise, [feign-netflix](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign) uses { and } to put variables and then replace it by arguments params annotated with `@Param("name")`, but you are using spring impl and it is do it for you if it is needed.